# _nativeError : Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Parser'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated

Tags: angular, webpack-2, typescript2.2

I'm getting this error:
Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Parser'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Parser' is decorated with Injectable. at NoAnnotationError.BaseError [as constructor]

My webpack bundle works fines get no errors but when I load the project, I get the error above.

Read somewhere that if I have my tsconfig like so:

```
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
```

I shouldn't need to use @injectables, very new to angular2 and TS.

in my webpack config I have this:

```
const vendor = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'core-js',
    'reflect-metadata',
    'rxjs',
    'ts-helpers',
    'zone.js'
];

entry: {
        app: [
            'reflect-metadata',
            'ts-helpers',
            'zone.js',
            'main'
        ],
        vendor
    },
```

Using angular 4.0.0-beta.1, webpack 2 and typescript 2.2.1

Thanks for any help.